# Find closest possible integer such that a/b is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have $a/b$ ($b$ is an integer but may not matter).

I want $a/b\prime$ to be an integer by leaving $a$ and choosing an integer $b\prime$ that is closest to $b$.

If it would be the other way round (choosing integer $a\prime$ closest to $a$) then the solution is simply

$$
a\prime = \operatorname{round}(a/b) b
$$

This should be trivial but I am somewhat stuck. I played around applying the usual candidates (round, floor, gcd, mod).

Comment: Why do you imagine that this would be easy?  You are asking for that divisor of $a$ nearest $b$....that would appear to require knowing the divisors of $a$.  In particular, you'd need to be able to tell if $a$ is a prime or not.  That's already a hard problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume $a$ is an integer, otherwise there is no such $b'$.  In order to have $a/b'$ an integer, you need $b'$ to be a divisor of $a$.  So find the divisors of $a$, and take $b'$ to be either the least divisor greater than $b$ or the greatest divisor less than $b$, whichever is closer.

Comment: The following MATLAB code provides the functionality: `divs = divisors(a);
[~,ind] = min(abs(divs-b));
bprime = divs(ind);`